# How to get the next page of graph.microsoft?

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am trying to get the groups and group members in the office 365 by API. 
I am able to get the group and group member list by using below API

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/e875D371-db4c-4371-b315-5970fXXXff76/members
```

Here my problem is I need to get the next page of the graph explorer. How could I get the next page of result?

I tried the `&$skiptoken` but it did not work or maybe I have not used correctly!

Can anyone kindly guide me to get the next page of the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below example code

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/9ckkqecb-43c6-4295-ac69-02bcaeac6570/members?$top=999&$select=id,displayName

this will give the first 999 result.

Comment: This is problematic if you have more than 999 results

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I don`t know another way to get the next page. So only.

Answer (score 1):

$skiptoken is described in the official docs [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/query_parameters#skiptoken).  To summarize, results that are paged will have a "@odata.nextLink" in the response.  This value is the resource you will use to get the rest of the results.  You can chain links together over and over, if necessary, until the entire result set is returned.